# function not working on modal in web browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have problem my function not working in mobile browser but when i open in browser desktop work i dont know why... maybe anybody know or have experience like me
i have try this code

```
$('body').on('click touchstart', '.show_range', function(event) { alert("hello"); })
```

work in desktop but not in mobile browser

i have try this code when i set id in my link

```
$(document).on("click", "#show_range", function(event){
 alert( "GO" ); 
 });
```

work in desktop but not in mobile browser

Comment: i have try touch still same not work in mobile browser but work in desktop :'(

Comment: i have check my version browse and web browser , i use chorme browser and web browser

Comment: @jefri, you want to popup modal on touch event ?

Comment: Sir, please post your mobile version and chrome version in the question

Comment: @AniketSahrawat oke sir version browser in desktop Version Chorme 54.0.2840.71 and in mobile browser  54.0.2840.85

Comment: are you using bootstrap modal ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
 $('#show_range').on("click", function(event){
     alert( "GO" ); 
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using bootstrap modal then make some change as below,

*in bootstrap-responsive.css*

```
.modal { 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 3%; 
    right: 3%; 
    left: 3%; 
    width: auto; 
    margin: 0; 
}
.modal-body { 
    height: 60%; 
}
```

*and in bootstrap.css*

```
.modal-body { 
    max-height: 350px; 
    padding: 15px; 
    overflow-y: auto; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
 }
```

OR
try this,

```
if( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i) ) {
    var styleEl = document.createElement('style'), styleSheet;
    document.head.appendChild(styleEl);
    styleSheet = styleEl.sheet;
    styleSheet.insertRule(".modal { position:absolute; bottom:auto; }", 0);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

thank for you help guys now my problem solved..
my mistake i set href="javascript:void()" and i change to href="#"